# Archlinux mute sound in browser only

Tags: arch-linux, audio

Is there a way how to mute all sounds in browser only? I need it to be done from command line. I'm currently using alsa mixer for mute (command `amixer set Master toggle`), but I can't find any way how to mute browser and not the other apps.

Comment: As far as I know you can mute stream per application only via Pulseaudio. But I don't know how to do it via command line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Doctoror Drive is correct, this can be done pretty simply with pulseaudio, but if you are using ALSA exclusively, it will be a much more difficult task.

With pulse, there are a variety of options. Both `pacmd` and `pactl` are capable of this, but it may seem overly complicated because of the significant number of options. Alternatively, you could use a community-contributed tool called `ponymix` (which is now in [community]) to very simply control both individual application streams and the system-wide server settings.

With pure ALSA, however, I am unsure if this is even possible.

Comment: it's not possible.

Comment: That's what I figured; I had never seen the ability to do so before.

Comment: @HalosGhost +1 for ponymix: and welcome!

Comment: Thanks jwr, I've been a longtime SE reader; figured it was about time I try to contribute something back.

Answer (score 2):

If you're not using pulseaudio you can create a softvol device in alsa:

```
pcm.aux {
    type softvol
    slave.pcm pcm.default

    control {
            name "AUX"
            card 0
    }
    hint.description "softvol für AUX"
}
```

Then configure your browser to use the "vdr" device. During the first use, a new mixer control will be created and appear e.g. in `alsamixer`.